# website inside iFrame lost it's responsiveness

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have the following html code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <title>  Test iFrame </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
         <div id="top-banner">
            <div id="offdeck-ads-div" class="offgroup" style="height: 69px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px auto; background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); position: relative; box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 2px 3px; -webkit-box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 2px 3px; z-index: 50; clear: both; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
               <div id="ads" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                  <div align="center">
                    <a href="#" accesskey="">
                        <img src="http://telkomselprod.amobee.com/content/4040581/85733614/85733613.gif" alt="">
                    </a>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <hr style="margin-top:2px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:1px;">
               <div id="toolbar" style="width:100%; text-align: center;">
                  <div style="width:300px; margin: 0px auto;">
                     <div style="text-align:right; width: 295px; display:inline-block; height:12px; vertical-align: top;">

                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="middle">
            <div id="left-banner">
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <iframe id="main-frame" scrolling="no" src="http://www.shopious.com/" height="7367" style="height: 7367px;">
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="right-banner">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="bottom-banner">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="showbutton" class="sh-div sh-div-top-bottom sh-div-top " style="display: none;"><span class="showbar"><a id="btn-show" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding: 5px; font-size: 10px; font-family: verdana; color: black; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">show ad</a></span></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I try to open this html inside my iPhone the responsiveness of my site disappears. It shows the full width of my site. How do I prevent this from happening? I think the issue has to do with viewport, but I am not sure how.

Easy way to reproduce the issue is to copy and paste the html above and open it into an iPhone simulator.

Comment: The iframe has a width, which acts as its viewport. Try making this iframe 100% wide or give it a width.

Comment: @MaraisRossouw the thing is that I have no control over the iframe width as this is injected by my phone carrier.. any other ways?

Comment: Do you have control over its parent? Maybe you could inject a js script that applies the width?